# How to write text to console with 64-bit assembler with modern Windows 10 updates?

Tags: windows, assembly, 64-bit

I've found a number of 64-bit assembler "Hello World" tutorials online for Windows, but none of them appear to work on my machine with the latest Windows 10 updates. In particular, `ExitProcess` continues to work, but `WriteFile` and `WriteConsoleA` silently fail.

Can someone describe the new ABI for this system call, or provide a fully qualified nasm/yasm example for `_write`, `write`, `fprintf`, `printf`, or similar functions with a more stable interface? (I am not interested in `MessageBoxA` or other graphical functions at the moment.) Please note any DLL's required aside from kernel32.dll, msvcrt.dll that declare these external functions.

Comment: sure that `WriteConsole` work ok

Answer (score 1):

In the given example you should use 64-bit space for variables `stdout` and `bytesWritten`:

```
stdout       dq 0
bytesWritten dq 0
```

or else saved data in `stdout` will be overwritten by `WriteFile` function.

Also you should restore stack after calling `WriteFile` function:

```
add rsp,8
```

or it'll stay corrupt.

Answer (score 0):

Evidently the online 64-bit Windows assembler tutorials do work, however, critical linker flags `/entry` and `/[subsystem:]console` were being mangled by Git Bash. So I've adopted the protection of wrapping the linker call in a PowerShell call, to ensure that the linker (either golink or link.exe) uses the correct mode, console, no matter which shell environment is running the linker command.

vsexec.bat:

```
:: Execute the specified command within a Visual Studio context,
:: where the necessary environment variables are sufficiently configured.
::
:: Usage: vsexec.bat <command>
::
:: Requires a Command Prompt or PowerShell context to operate.

call "C:\\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat" amd64 %*
```

hello.asm:

```
extern GetStdHandle
extern WriteFile
extern ExitProcess

section .rodata

msg db "Hello World!", 0x0d, 0x0a

msg_len equ $-msg
stdout_query equ -11
status equ 0

section .data

stdout dw 0
bytesWritten dw 0

section .text

global start

start:
    mov rcx, stdout_query
    call GetStdHandle
    mov [rel stdout], rax

    mov  rcx, [rel stdout]
    mov  rdx, msg
    mov  r8, msg_len
    mov  r9, bytesWritten
    push qword 0
    call WriteFile

    mov rcx, status
    call ExitProcess
```

Build steps:

```
$ nasm -f win64 hello.asm
$ powershell -Command "~\\vsexec.bat link /entry:start /subsystem:console hello.obj kernel32.lib"
```

Trace:

```
$ hello.exe
Hello World!
```

Final notes: I'm not sure what the exact proper stack and return policy is. The Windows documentation suggests that the stack be A) aligned to 16 bytes, B) provide 32 bytes per Windows API call, C) perform a `ret` at the end of each subroutine. However, when I try to do this, then I get segfaults. Not sure if nasm/link.exe are automatically performing some of the stack management work on my behalf or what, I guess I could check `objdump -xDz hello.exe` output to examine this further.

Comment: There is no secret stack management, it just happened to work. It's not entirely correct but that doesn't guarantee failure. By the way, those `stdout` and `bytesWritten` variables are allocated with a different size (word) than they are used (qword and dword)

Comment: also must be `lea  r9, bytesWritten`, not `mov` (and this variable must be `DD`, and better local in stack, not global)

Comment: @RbMm: This is NASM, `lea r9, bytesWritten` wouldn't not assemble because you left out the `[]` around the source operand.  `mov r9, bytesWritten` assembles to `mov r32, imm32` with the absolute address. (Or maybe `mov r64, sign_extended_imm32`, but probably not `mov r64, imm64` if you don't use a `qword` override, but don't do that).  To make PIC code, `lea r9, [rel bytesWritten]`.  (Or use `default rel`).  But yeah, static storage isn't needed at all here; stack space is good.

Comment: @PeterCordes - not note this (*nasm*) at begin. think about this in *masm* syntax, and think that here we got value of bytesWritten instead it address. my mistake.